# Difference between 'new' and '=' in relation to pointers

Tags: c++, c++11

These two pieces of code are creating very different results depending on the compiler and I don't understand why

```
node *active_node = new node;
```

vs

```
node current_node;
node *active_node;
active_node = &current_node;
```

From my understanding, I am manually creating a node object and assigning it to the active node pointer, same as the dynamic allocation above. However, they produce entirely different results in context of the program

Comment: From what resource are you learning C++ that doesn't  explain this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In this code:

```
node *active_node = new node;
```

You are allocating a `node` object in dynamic (heap) memory, and then assigning its address to `active_node`. The `node` object will live until the program is terminated, or until you `delete` it.

In this code:

```
node current_node;
node *active_node;
active_node = &current_node;
```

You are allocating `current_node` in automatic (stack) memory, and then assigning its address to `active_node`. The `current_node` object will die when it goes out of scope (end of the function, etc), leaving `active_node` to point at invalid memory.

Comment: A followup on that, if node *active_node = new node; lives until the program is terminated, why am I not able to delete it in the destructor of the class inside which it is created? It says "active_node is not defined in this scope" but then it's causing memory leaks

Comment: @ARNAVRAMKRISHNAN The way `active_node` is being declared in your example, it is a **local variable** to whatever procedure is calling `new`.  That is why it is unknown to the destructor. You need to make it be a member of the class instead.

Comment: @ARNAVRAMKRISHNAN because the variable containing the pointer is out of scope :) As Remy says, you need to declare is a member variable. Also, Remy, thanks for editing my answer.

Comment: @ARNAVRAMKRISHNAN if my answer (and Remy's comment) helped you understand the problem, please mark it as accepted (the green tick near the answer), thank you!

Comment: While I understand that it was created as a local variable, is there a way to free up the actual memory space node object is using from somewhere outside the method (without making it a class object of course)? Or does it just dangles in the memory and there's no way to reference it once the method goes out of scope?

Comment: Once the method finishes and you have no pointer that points at the memory (allocated using `new`), there is no way to free it. You need to keep the pointer somewhere safe, so that you can later call `delete` on it, thus freeing the memory.

Comment: @ARNAVRAMKRISHNAN "is there a way to free up the actual memory space node object is using from somewhere outside the method" Return the pointer from the method or, rather than declaring it locally, pass it as a reference parameter to the method.

Comment: The heap is also sometimes called the global store.  I think in both C and C++ it is an implementation detail.  I use a separate (not terribly performant; for finding mistakes in debug builds) heap for C-style malloc/free, C++ new/delete, and C++ new[]/delete[].